# How to use the range tool correctly?

Tags: python, widget, bokeh

I have a plot where the x values are date time objects and the y values are integers. I added a range tool to it. I want to write a bokeh server app that responds to changes to the end values of the range. I have noticed that the values are converted from the Python `datetime` class to `floats`. Why and how can this be prevented and is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
import datetime

import bokeh.plotting
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Range1d, RangeTool


time_strs = ['2019-07-11 10:00:00', '2019-07-11 10:15:00', '2019-07-11 10:30:00', '2019-07-11 10:45:00']
time_objs = [datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for time_str in time_strs]
data = dict(x=time_objs, y=[5,4,6,5])

timeline = bokeh.plotting.figure(x_axis_type='datetime')
timeline.x(x='x', y='y', source=ColumnDataSource(data))

def print_values(attr, old, new):
    print(attr)
    print(old, type(old))
    print(new, type(new))

range = Range1d(start=time_objs[0], end=time_objs[-1])
range.on_change('end', print_values)
range_tool = RangeTool(x_range=range)
timeline.add_tools(range_tool)

curdoc().add_root(timeline)
```

Running the app and moving the end of the range tool prints the following:

```
end
2019-07-11 10:45:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
1562841763259.6685 <class 'float'>
end
1562841763259.6685 <class 'float'>
1562841249116.022 <class 'float'>
end
1562841249116.022 <class 'float'>
1562841074088.3977 <class 'float'>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The underlying data format for Bokeh datetimes is a numerical timestamp, denominated in milliseconds-since-epoch. Various common datetime types are automatically converted to timestamp values on ingest as a convenience, but you will need to convert these timestamp results to datetimes using standard APIs:

```
In [4]: datetime.fromtimestamp(1562841074088.3977 / 1000)
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 11, 3, 31, 14, 88398)
```